# install kernel headers without overwriting old headers

Tags: linux, kernel, glibc

I've built a newer (3.16-rc2) kernel which is running fine.  My userspace program needs to link against the newer headers as it uses some new definitions in fcntrl.h etc.

My question is how do I preserve the headers of the old kernel when running "make headers_install" ?

If run

```
make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`
```

Header definitions clash as /usr/src/include is still in the PATH.

Whats the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the old ones if you actually want to use the new ones?  It's not going to make any difference to anything that's already compiled and installed, and if this is the kernel now used on the system, then in the future, the new headers are the ones that are best applicable.

Comment: Ideally, it would not make a difference. However, in the event that we need to use the older kernel, our userspace programs may not work on the older kernel.  I just want to safeguard against this event.

Comment: If you *need* to use the header from the newer kernel, because, as you say, "my userspace program needs to link against the newer headers as it uses some new definitions", then what you are saying is *my userspace program **cannot work** with an older kernel*, so that's that.

Comment: Those features in the userspace program that use newer kernel mechanisms can be disabled.  I just want to be able to preserve the old header structure. Perhaps I'm being paranoid but ... I rather imagine there is a way to handle this. I suppose I could save off the old headers and reinstall them.

Comment: Why don't you just make a backup copy of the old headers in a different place?

Comment: @OP which distro do you use? At least ubuntu variants keep the old kernel automatically. So I assume this is at least a bit distro dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `#include` two headers with an identical path, but you can install one outside of the normal paths and have it supersede those when you compile by using the appropriate switch (for gcc, `-I`).  I think you understand that stuff already, so it should not take too much thinking to recognize that you if you place more than one `asm/fcntl.h` in normal include directories, *only one of them will apply anyway*.

I don't think you have much to worry about, however.  Starting with some of your comments:

> Those features in the userspace program that use newer kernel mechanisms can be disabled.

This is good.  If you need `#define NEWVALUE 666` in order to **compile**, and that involves a feature that will only work on a newer kernel and you can catch or disable the use of such otherwise, then the sections that actually apply `NEWVALUE` will never get called.  Remember, it's not that there's no header defining this available when the old kernel is running -- even if there was, it wouldn't matter, since the real problem at runtime is that you've effectively invoked a non-existent part of the kernel [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). You don't need any headers at all present just to **run** an executable, so going back to the old kernel won't matter for that.

> Perhaps I'm being paranoid but...

Yes and no.  If this is a system where various people arbitrary swap in different kernel headers in order to exploit new features when compiling stuff that's going to be left around and run later using an older kernel, then paranoia is an appropriate response, lol.  However, there's probably not much that really falls into this category.

Distros replace the kernel headers at every upgrade, but the list of user land things they have to replace at the same time usually seems not so long (if it exists at all).  I suppose that's in part because maintaining backward compatibility in this context is pretty easy, but I think it's also because things in this context don't change drastically over time.

> I suppose I could save off the old headers and reinstall them.

You could do that, or you could replace them from the appropriate source when needed (`make headers_install`); if it's a distro kernel and you are worried they may be patched, the distro should have a source package for it.